# When The Undead warlock (UA) uses their Spirit Projection ability, do their spirit and body share a single pool of hitpoints?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, unearthed-arcana, hit-points, spirits

The Undead warlock patron can be found [here](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#TheUndeadUA) at DnDBeyond or [here](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/unearthed-arcana/subclasses-part-4) direct from Wizards of the Coast.

The subclass is freely available playtest content, so I will reproduce the feature here:

> **Spirit Projection**
>
> *14th-level Undead feature*
>
> Your body is now simply a vessel for your spirit. As an action, you can project your spirit from your body. The body you leave behind is unconscious and in a state of suspended animation.
>
> Your spirit can remain outside your body for up to 1 hour or until your concentration is broken (as if concentrating on a spell). When your projection ends, your spirit returns to your body or your body magically teleports to your spirit’s space (your choice).
>
> While projecting your spirit, you gain the following benefits:
>
> - Your spirit and body gain resistance to bludgeoning, piercing, and slashing damage.
> - When you cast a spell of the conjuration or necromancy school, the spell doesn’t require verbal, somatic, or material components that lack a gold cost.
> - You have a flying speed equal to your walking speed and can hover. You can move through creatures and objects as if they were difficult terrain, but you take 1d10 force damage if you end your turn inside a creature or an object.
> - While you are using your Form of Dread, once during each of your turns when you deal necrotic damage to a creature, you regain hit points equal to half the amount of necrotic damage dealt.
>
> Once you use this feature, you can’t do so again until you finish a long rest.

This class feature speaks of *you* and *your body* as though they are distinct entities in some sense. It seems clear that when the feature says "you" it is referring to "your spirit", and refers to your body as "your body" or "the body".

In [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/174242/62294), Ben Barden briefly analyzes this feature and makes the assertion:

> Nothing is said about funny things happening with HP, so presumably it's all coming out of the same HP pool. Nothing is said about effects, so, by default, anything that hit either the person or the spirit would affect the whole. So... basically, they're both a creature, but they're both the same creature, who now happens to have two locations they can be targeted from.

I'd like to see a more detailed analysis of this feature so that we do not have to say "presumably" as Ben says in their analysis.

Do your spirit and your body share a single pool of hitpoints while using the Spirit Projection feature?

Comment: Looking over the question to answer it, I found that there was just more and more questions I had about the ability, but they almost certainly share hp.

Comment: @Daveman It certainly seems to be poorly written, IMO.

Comment: Can you make attacks as a spirit? Do conditions carry over after the ability ends? If a condition is afflicted to the body do you suffer it? (obviously not the unconscious?) Does your spirit share your AC (which was likely wearing armor)? If your spirit has a spiritual equivalent to your equipment, what if your body's actual equipment is removed? Right now a DM running this ability is pretty much having to design it themselves using the written ability as inspiration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Your body and spirit share HP.

The closest ability to compare this one to is [astral projection](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/astral-projection). They are actually very similar abilities in concept. However, astral projection clearly indicates that the creation is a duplicate, with its own game statistics.

> Your astral body resembles your mortal form in almost every way, replicating your game statistics and possessions.

> Your astral form is a separate incarnation. Any damage or other effects that apply to it have no effect on your physical body, nor do they persist when you return to it.

It also clearly defines that your body or projection could reach 0 hp independently.

> If a creature's original body or its astral form drops to 0 hit points, the spell ends for that creature.

Where Spirit Projection hints that this is YOU in two ways.

> Your body is now simply a vessel for your spirit.

> While projecting your spirit, you gain the following benefits:

> Your spirit and body gain resistance to bludgeoning, piercing, and slashing damage.

It states that YOU gain the benefits of gaining resistance, to body and spirit.

No where does it include language like astral projection considering your body and projection as different entities.

Ultimately this is part of the play test content. Things like this need to be tested and hashed out. And likely rewritten to be more clear before it is officially published. But to me it is clear that if they wanted your body and spirit to be two independent entities, they would have included more of the wording similar to the spell astral projection.

Obviously this could change if they reword the content (as happens with Unearthed Arcana). But as written there just is nothing clearly creating two sets of game statistics.